R tinytex cannot connect to CTAN mirrors during docker build
I'm trying to build a Docker container to develop PDF reports for download through an R Shiny app. As such, I am installing TinyTeX to manage all the dependencies. I have my build setup through a Dockerfile and a dummy report at the end that should run and initialize any files needed to make it work. I have tried this on both hub.docker.com and my local machine with no success. My local install of RStudio runs the Shiny apps successfully.
My minimal Dockerfile is:
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.3.2

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y\
    && apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove --purge

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('rmarkdown','tinytex')); tinytex::install_tinytex(force=TRUE)"

COPY dummy.Rmd /root/dummy.Rmd

RUN R -e "rmarkdown::render('/root/dummy.Rmd',output_file='dummy.pdf')"

and dummy.Rmd is
---
title: "Dummy Report"
author: "Me"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ["booktabs","anyfontsize"]
documentclass: article
classoption: a4paper
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{longtable}
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{multirow}
  - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  - \usepackage{wrapfig}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{colortbl}
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
  - \usepackage{tabu}
  - \usepackage{threeparttable}
  - \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
  - \usepackage{anyfontsize}
  - \usepackage[]{fancyhdr}
---

## R Markdown
Sample Text

No matter which mirror I set, I am getting some variation of the message:
cannot contact mirror.ctan.org, returning a backbone server!
/root/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: TLPDB::from_file could not initialize from: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
/root/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: Maybe the repository setting should be changed.
/root/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: More info: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html
! LaTeX Error: File `multirow.sty' not found.
! Emergency stop.

whether I am running this build locally or on the docker hub server.
tinytex::is_tinytex() returns TRUE.
Edit: Fixed syntax error and dependency error, but does not reproduce the error.

Your code is a syntax error: install.packages('rmarkdown','tinytex') is trying to install package "rmarkdown" into lib='tinytex'.

When I fix that typo and build it, I encounter the error Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found. When I look in the image I do not see a pandoc executable, suggesting we need to run /rocker_scripts/install_pandoc.sh. Do you not need this?

Fixing that problem, I then fail with Can't locate File/Find.pm in @INC, which means that the perl availability is not being found correctly/completely. I'm not really certain how to help, after fixing two other bugs here I can't even get to that error. If your Dockerfile is reduced in order to provide a minimal reproducible question, fantastic! But ... too-reduced. Please try your reduced code when asking a question so that we don't end up spiraling on unrelated problems like these.

Very fair. I wrote this very quickly and definitely skipped some of the steps in my existing file. Let me update this, but it looks like I should probably change the base image as suggested by datawookie to bypass this problem entirely.

Konrad Rudolph's comment on datawookie's answer was correct; the tidyverse image adds a lot of other dependencies. I simplified the image a lot by using a rocker script still in the image.
Dockerfile:
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.3.2

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y\
    && apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove --purge

# Copied these next lines from rocker scripts to properly install texlive
ENV CTAN_REPO=https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/bin/linux
RUN /rocker_scripts/install_texlive.sh

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('rmarkdown','tinytex'))"

COPY dummy.Rmd .

#The dummy markdown should automatically install all the needed dependencies for further .Rmd files
RUN R -e "rmarkdown::render('dummy.Rmd')"

Thank you all for your help! I'm not sure what was causing the original problem, but it was most likely a misconfigured installation. And my own inexperience (read incompetence). I apologize for not submitting a runnable reduced problem that replicated the issue, but thank you for helping me resolve it regardless.

In your original Dockerfile you should have
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('rmarkdown','tinytex'));"

The two package names need to be passed as a vector, so wrap them in c().
I'd suggest rather using the rocker/tidyverse base image though, which is set up for using TinyTeX.
FROM rocker/tidyverse:4.3.2

RUN Rscript -e 'tinytex::install_tinytex()'

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux/"

RUN tlmgr install \
        multirow \
        colortbl \
        wrapfig \
        pdflscape \
        varwidth \
        threeparttable \
        ulem \
        anyfontsize \
        fancyhdr

COPY dummy.Rmd .
CMD R -e "rmarkdown::render('dummy.Rmd')"


The unfortunate side-effect is that rocker/tidyverse pulls in a ton of other dependencies, many of which are probably not required for OP, and may cause issues down the line.

Thank you! I was avoiding using that base image to maintain a smaller image, but I think now that I'm using RMarkdown, my reasoning is flawed. I already use dplyr, data.table, and some databasing. Is there a reason you use RUN tlmgr install instead of tinytex::tlmgr_install()?

While TinyTeX is better than many LaTeX distributions, anything with LaTeX is likely to be not-small.
